# How can i set the right shape to make predictions for my CNN model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, reshape, image-classification

i'm having some problem with prediction phase of my image Classiffier Model in Python.
With the input image size of 128x128 i created model with a model like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32,3,padding="same", activation="relu", input_shape=(128,128,3)))
model.add(MaxPool2D())

model.add(Conv2D(32, 3, padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D())

model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D())
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(2, activation="softmax"))

model.summary()
```

I'm getting no errors after training the model and using it for predicting one single image from my validation dataset:

```
model = load_model('modelimi.h5')
 
image = load_img('sample_space.png', target_size=(128, 128))
img = np.array(image)
img = img / 255.0
img = img.reshape(1,128, 128,3)
label = model.predict(img)
```

The Problem starts when i try to predict the live screen capture:

```
while True:

    image = grab_screen(region=(50, 130, 1000, 650))
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    image = cv2.Canny(image, threshold1=200, threshold2=400)
    image = cv2.resize(image,(128,128))
    #cv2.imwrite(filename, image)
    
    img = np.array(image)
    img = img / 255.0
    img = img.reshape(1,128, 128,3)
    label = model.predict(img)
```

The error that i got is this:

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) Input In [1], in <cell line: 30>()
> 36 img = np.array(image)
> 37 img = img / 255.0
> ---> 38 img = img.reshape(1,128, 128,3)
> 39 label = model.predict(img)
> 41 if label[0][0]<label[0][1]:
>
> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 16384 into shape
> (1,128,128,3)

I tried to reduce the number of channels of captured screen data to one but i couldn't apply that to the code either. The Preprocessing and normalisation was done like this:

```
x_train = []
y_train = []
x_val = []
y_val = []

for feature, label in train:
  x_train.append(feature)
  y_train.append(label)

for feature, label in val:
  x_val.append(feature)
  y_val.append(label)


x_train = np.array(x_train) / 255
x_val = np.array(x_val) / 255

x_train.reshape(-1, img_size, img_size, 1)
y_train = np.array(y_train)

x_val.reshape(-1, img_size, img_size, 1)
y_val = np.array(y_val)
```

Comment: Never post screenshots. Please, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You are using a (128,128, 1) image as input. Indeed, you use `cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY` converting your image to grayscale (hence 1 channel).

The error tells you it cannot reshape 16384 (=128x128) into (128,128,3).